# String split with delimiter as *** in Java

Tags: java, string, spring

```
public class TestStringSplit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String bal = "IND|TEST|***|Cricket|***";
        String[] patterns = org.springframework.util.StringUtils.split(bal,
                "***");
        System.out.println("SPRING Framework String Split");
        for (String pt : patterns) {
            System.out.println("Pattern " + pt);
        }

        System.out.println("************************");

        patterns = org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.split(bal,
                "***");
        System.out.println("Apache Commons Lang String Split");
        for (String pt : patterns) {
            System.out.println("Pattern " + pt);
        }

        System.out.println("************************");

        patterns = bal.split("***");
        System.out.println("JDK String Split");
        for (String pt : patterns) {
            System.out.println("Pattern " + pt);
        }

    }
}
```

Result for the above is

SPRING Framework String Split

```
Pattern IND|TEST|

Pattern |Cricket|***
```

---

Apache Commons Lang String Split

```
Pattern IND|TEST|

Pattern |Cricket|
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0
***
^
```

Why is that the default JDK doesnt give me the required result but rather the exception..and what should be the pattern for getting the values

Regards

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape '*' as it is a special character in regex:

```
patterns = bal.split("\\*\\*\\*");
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the response!!                                          On a separate note, which is better in terms of performance ?

Comment: Direct escaping might be a tiny bit faster than Pattern.quote() as you only create one String and don't have to convert it, but it really usually doesn't matter, the difference should be very, very small I guess. Use the one you find more readable on a case by case basis. Of course if you want to use special regex characters and don't want to escape them, then Pattern.quote will not work.

Answer (score 1):

`*` in regex means "0 or more". It is a special character that has to be escaped in a regex string. Also, since `\` is a special character for a string, it also has to be escaped.

```
String[] patterns = org.springframework.util.StringUtils.split(bal, "\\*\\*\\*");
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` uses a regular expression  the `*` character as its main argument. `*` is a wilcard character that is used to match 0 or more characters and needs to be escaped. As an alternative you could do

```
patterns = bal.split(Pattern.quote("***"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`String#split` uses regex as argument, while rest of presented by you methods use literals. If you want to convert regex to its literal representation you need to escape all its its metacharacters.
You can do it manually like `\\*`, `[*]`, or just use method like `Pattern.quote` to do this for you

```
bal.split(Pattern.quote("***"))
```